# Triggering Durable Function throws Null Reference exception

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I have the following setup to test my Durable Function.

```cs
public class TestDurableFunction
{
    private readonly ITestRepository _testRepository;

    public TestDurableFunction(ITestRepository testRepository)
    {
        _testRepository = testRepository; // needed for later use
    }
    
    [FunctionName("TimerTrigger")]
    public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 1 * * *", RunOnStartup = true)] TimerInfo myTimer, [DurableClient] IDurableClient starter, ILogger logger)
    {
        try
        {
            await starter.StartNewAsync("OrchestrateSavings", null);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            logger.LogFunctionError(nameof(Run), nameof(TestDurableFunction), exception);
        }
    }

    [FunctionName("OrchestrateTest")]
    public async Task<int> OrchestrateTest([OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
    {
        await Task.CompletedTask;
        return 10;
    }
}
```

When I start this function locally, then the `TimerTrigger` function starts with no problems. This function then calls my `OrchestrateTest` Durable Function.

But that immediately throws the following error in the Command Prompt window:

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost: Unable to load metadata for
> function 'OrchestrateTest'. Function 'OrchestrateTest (Orchestrator)'
> was aborted. Reason: An internal error occurred while attempting to
> execute this function. The execution will be aborted and retried.
> Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an
> instance of an object.

Anyone any idea what the issue could be?

Comment: is your issue resolved with provided answer?

Comment: Anyone searching for this error message, you get the same message if you missout     [FunctionName("xxx")] and have RunOnStartup = True on the method

Answer (score 2):

As per your code the orchestrator function you are invoking is `OrchestrateSavings`; however there is not orchestrator function registered with that name. As per posted code the orchestrator function name is `OrchestrateTest`. So change the line to

`await starter.StartNewAsync("OrchestrateTest", null);`

in the `Run` method.